# How to adjust line width with hotkey in powerpoint? (2010 or above)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint, hotkeys

How to adjust line width in powerpoint? My powerpoint version is 2010. I have known hotkeys such as control shift + arrows to adjust block widths and heights.

However, I do not know how to adjust line widths with hotkey? Such as to adjust lines of arrows or text box. I have tried to find some hotkey tables and have not found any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a shortcut built in for "thicker" or "thinner" outline. If you want to avoid the mouse you can go Alt > H > S > O and the use up and down arrow keys.

To make it shorter you can add the outline weight to the quick access toolbar which would make it Alt > 1  and then up/down arrow.